# Jquery UI Sortable getting error

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, yii, jquery-ui-sortable

i am using jquery sortable in my project which is in Yii framework.
My project is using jQuery v1.8.3 and i can't upgrade jquery version as it has some dependencies in the project.

I am following the following link

https://jqueryui.com/sortable/#empty-lists

I have tried the example in the code but getting the following error.

```
TypeError: e.ui.isOverAxis is not a function
```

Kindly help me to figure out the solution.

Comment: Show us your code or create demo on jsfiddle

Comment: try using a lower version of jquery ui

Comment: @Tushar i am using same code as mentioned in the link. But there is some thing wrong with the Jquery version or jquery-ui

Comment: @AhsanMohyuddin as Cerlin Boss said lowering version might work as `isOverAxis` was removed in 1.11, depricated in 1.10. So 1.10 might still work for you. Still odd, considering Jquery 1.6+ is supported. Changing version seems a bandage fix, and not fixing the problem. what file generates this error? Jquery? Jquery UI? Some plugin maybe?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone stumbling across this, to remove jQuery or jQuery UI from Yii you can add the following to your application:

```
// Removes jQuery and jQuery UI
Yii::app()->clientScript->scriptMap=array('jquery.min.js'=>false, 'jquery-ui.min.js'=>false);

// Removes jQuery UI only
Yii::app()->clientScript->scriptMap=array('jquery-ui.min.js'=>false);
```

Then you can include your own version of jQuery manually